# Javascript function is changing a variable out of context

Tags: javascript

As you can see in the code below at any moment i change the `this.attributes_` variable, but it changes anyway.. Anyone here already faced this before ?

```
class Placement {
    constructor(attributes) {
        this.attributes_ = attributes;
        this.adElement_ = null;
    }

    run() {
        console.log(this.attributes_);
        this.adElement_ = createElementWithAttributes('div', this.attributes_);
        console.log(this.attributes_);
    }
}

function createElementWithAttributes(tagName, attributes) {
    const element = window.document.createElement(tagName);

    return addAttributesToElement(element, parseAttributes(attributes));
}

function addAttributesToElement(element, attributes) {
    for (const attr in attributes) {
        if(attributes.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
            element.setAttribute(attr, attributes[attr]);
        }
    }

    return element;
}

function parseAttributes(attributeObject) {
    attributeObject['a'] = 123;

    return attributeObject;
}

new Placement({'a': 'b'}).run();
```

I already tried to create a new variable before calling the `createElementWithAttributes` function, but it didn't work.

I have no ideas what to try, I would like to ask your help to try to solve this problem.

Comment: It doesn't change a variable but a property of an object. This line `attributeObject['a'] = 123;` overwrites the property `a` of the object you pass to this function.

Comment: inside the parseAttributes method

Comment: Yes, but `attributeObject` supposed to be a new variable, not the same one. I've tried to create a new variable inside `parseAttributes ` function, but i still get the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were passing attributes in function parseAttributes which is same object this.attributes_. JS will pass it by reference and any change in it will modify the original object. Use below code:

```js
class Placement {
    constructor(attributes) {
        this.attributes_ = attributes;
        this.adElement_ = null;
    }

    run() {
        console.log(this.attributes_);
        this.adElement_ = createElementWithAttributes('div', this.attributes_);
        console.log(this.attributes_);
    }
}

function createElementWithAttributes(tagName, attributes) {
    const element = window.document.createElement(tagName);

    return addAttributesToElement(element, parseAttributes({...attributes}));
}

function addAttributesToElement(element, attributes) {
    for (const attr in attributes) {
        if(attributes.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
            element.setAttribute(attr, attributes[attr]);
        }
    }

    return element;
}

function parseAttributes(attributeObject) {
    attributeObject['a'] = 123;

    return attributeObject;
}

new Placement({'a': 'b'}).run();
```